# IE9 and self.close()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframed "pop-up" window in InnovaStudio WYSIWYG Editor (5.3).  It is used to place a link from navigation into the text.  Once a link is clicked, the pop-up should close.

This code works in all browsers except Internet Explorer 9:

```
$('#InternalLinkSelector').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    (opener ? opener:openerWin).oUtil.obj.insertLink($this.attr('href'), $this.html(), null, null);
    self.close();
});
```

The pop-up has it's own close button in the upper corner that calls `ISWindow.objs['`UNIQUE_ID_STRING`'].close();`.  I tried rewriting the code to use `ISWindow`, but it exhibits the same behavior, working in all browsers but IE9:

```
$('#InternalLinkSelector').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    (opener?opener:openerWin).oUtil.obj.insertLink($this.attr('href'), $this.html(), null, null);
    // Find the window object to close it
    for (var i in top.ISWindow.objs) {
        if ('function' == typeof top.ISWindow.objs[i].close) {
            top.ISWindow.objs[i].close();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried just `window.close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `console.log(self.close)` and traced it to these lines in InnovaStudio's `istoolbar.js` code:

```
me.rt.frm.contentWindow.closeWin=function() {
    me.close();
};
me.rt.frm.contentWindow.close=function() {
    me.close();
};
```

So, thinking that IE9 may not be seeing the `close()` for some reason, I changed my code to use `closeWin()`:

```
$('#InternalLinkSelector').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    (opener ? opener : openerWin).oUtil.obj.insertLink($this.attr('href'), $this.html(), null, null);
    self.closeWin();
});
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

Try `window.close()` instead of `self.close()`

Comment: `window.close()` behaves the same way.