# Window.open doesn't return the window reference IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reference, internet-explorer-9, window.open

I'm using a script to mount my mailto link and call the default email editor. But I can't use document.location.href because of some bug in IE9, so I use window.open. It works. But I need to close the IE windows opened.

The problem is the window.close doesn't return the window reference.

```
function doMailto() {
   var sMailto = 'mailto:?bcc=';
   sMailto += document.getElementById('<%= txtEmails.ClientID %>').value;
   out = window.open(sMailto);
   out.close();  //CANT CALL CLOSE, BECAUSE OUT IS NULL
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate(with solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100451/ie9-and-self-close

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra paren at the end of the assignment line.

Also, are you trying to close the window in the same function as assigned? If not, you may need to declare the window variable outside the function so it can be closed when needed.

Comment: I wish to close these new IE window (or return to the previous URL), while default mail client is open (it's a independent process and I don't want to close it by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

aside the syntax errors (two commas, two parentesis closing)...

you are opening a window that is external to the browser, your default mail client. You cannot control it through javascript.

Maybe it's an immediacy problem, try using:

```
var out = window.open()...
setTimeout(function(){out.close()}, 200)
```

and fiddle with the 200ms to see if it works then.

try

```
top.location.href = 'mailto:....';
```

you won't need to open or close any windows this way

Comment: I changed these syntax errors, I posted the wrong code. But the fact is, it's opening the default mail client, but also another window along with it.

Comment: André, your code worked as it is.
But I need to open the default mail client, and when I use window.open('mailto:....') it returns a null reference for out variable!

Comment: Your modification leads to a blank page. I'm aware this is caused because of the Internet Protected Mode (if I turn it off, it'll work), but I can't turn it off once I must not rely on users changing local configs.

Comment: sorry then, i'm all outta love

Comment: The great problem with this mailto is the length that's greater than 500 chars.